# Why the following simple & strict iptable rule will prevent apt update from performing?

Tags: iptables

I setup the following simple yet strict rule, so that our server only accept incoming

1. ssh
2. http
3. https

But, once such rule is set, I notice I can no longer perform apt update

```
root@wenote-droplet:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
root@wenote-droplet:~# apt update
Err:1 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrors.digitalocean.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
0% [Working]
```

---

If I drop all the rule, then apt update is not a problem?

```
root@wenote-droplet:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
root@wenote-droplet:~# apt update
Get:1 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Get:3 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:4 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
```

---

May I know why it is so? I thought, during `apt update`, only the **Chain Output** rule is (which is ACCEPT default policy) is used?

As, during `apt update`, we are not acting as HTTP server, but we are acting as client which issues OUTPUT traffic.

Answer (score 2):

IPTables rules apply to all IP packets. In TCP connections, the server both sends packets via `OUTPUT` chain and receives packets via `INPUT` chain.

In your rules, you are dropping all the packets from the receiving direction with the `DROP` rule.

You need to use connection tracking in order to allow receiving packets for TCP connections that the server itself has started.

This is a basic ruleset to allow it:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j accept
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

First rule allows incoming packets for established conncetions.

Second rule allows new incoming connections for ports 22,80,443.

Last rule sets the default policy for `INPUT` chain packets to `DROP`.

It is also good practice to allow incoming ICMP packets:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```